# mod_rewrite page.php?param=parameter to parameter.html

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have a site that has been written in standard html with a number of products for which the client has had to create a manual page each time. Im now looking to get this onto php and have created a database and php files to serve the products.

All is good however they would like to use the current url setup if possible ie

www.mysite.co.uk/this-is-a-product.html

rather than
www.mysite.co.uk/view_product.php?product=this-is-a-product

they are quite insistent on having the .html on the end (and that would mean all the current links out there work as well).

Im sure this is a fairly standard kind of rewrite but no matter what searches Ive done cant seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ view_product.php?product=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: @aty Thanks for that, Ive used both of these and both worked fine on my test site with slightly different parameters. The test site I tried it on used an id as the parameter so the URL looked like www.mysite2.co.uk/30.html and all worked fine. Ive now moved it onto the live site in question (without changing anything now I receive 404 errors when trying www.mysite.co.uk/ice+cream+cone.html. Ive checked everything and all appears to be correct. Both sites are on my webhosting, both have the same setup etc so there shouldnt be any difference in the mod_rewrite rules etc

Comment: @aty apologies, Ive realised that my original query made one simple yet fatal error! where I had ice-cream-cone.html I should have pointed out that the url is encoded and therefore looks more like ice+cream+cone.html, from the testing Ive done so far it appears that the spaces (+) are the problems as the regex supplied "appears" to be taking a word from the URL and therefore falls over. What I basically need is the filename - the .html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html$ view_product.php?product=$1 [L,NC]
```